# Running a for loop for renaming column

Tags: r, for-loop

In my data set, I want to rename my column number 56 to 80. Instead of going manually, I created a list of names that I want the new names to be set as. Then I run a for loop which runs without any error however every single column gets renamed as the last value in the list I created. Any suggestion on what am I doing wrong here. Please see below my code:-

To create the list:-

```r
mylist <- list("Jun-20", "Jul-20", "Aug-20", "Sep-20", "Oct-20", 
    "Nov-20", "Dec-20", "Jan-21", "Feb-21", "Mar-21", "Apr-21", 
    "May-21", "Jun-21", "Jul-21", "Aug-21", "Sep-21", "Oct-21", 
    "Nov-21", "Dec-21", "Jan-22", "Feb-22", "Mar-22", "Apr-22", 
    "May-22", "Jun-22")
```

And then I run the for loop:-

```r
for (j in 56:80) {
    for (i in 1:length(mylist)) {
        names(CNS7)[j] <- mylist[[i]]
    }
}
```

Here the j values are the column range (56 to 80) which I want to rename. My end result comes as all the columns from 56 to 80 gets renamed as "Jun-22".

Comment: Isn't this just `names(CNS7)[56:80] <- unlist(mylist)`.  Also, instead of a list, you could have created a vector with `c()` in place of `list()`, then it is direct i.e. `names(CNS7)[56:80] <- myvec`

Comment: Yes this worked, however I didnt think of this. Writing that loop was coming as top of the mind solution and thats what I tried. However your solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`names<-` assignment is vectorized i.e. it can assign names to more than one column.

```
names(CNS7)[56:80] <- unlist(mylist)
```

Note that `colnames` or `names` are all vectors.  Therefore, constructing a vector will be more direct

```
myvec <- c("Jun-20", "Jul-20", "Aug-20", "Sep-20", "Oct-20", 
    "Nov-20", "Dec-20", "Jan-21", "Feb-21", "Mar-21", "Apr-21", 
    "May-21", "Jun-21", "Jul-21", "Aug-21", "Sep-21", "Oct-21", 
    "Nov-21", "Dec-21", "Jan-22", "Feb-22", "Mar-22", "Apr-22", 
    "May-22", "Jun-22")
names(CNS7)[56:80] <- myvec
```

---

By doing a nested loop, it is looping over each column in 'j', `length(mylist)` and thus, the `names` will be changed in each iteration and it gets the value of the last element of 'mylist'.  These are vectorized operations in `R` and thus doing a nested loop here will result in incorrect results.  In addition, it is not efficient (`o(n^2)`)

If we need a loop in (`o(n)`), create an index object (`ind`), then loop over the sequence of 'ind', subset the 'ind' element to get the corresponding `names` and assign it to `list` element from the sequence

```
ind <- 56:80
for(i in seq_along(ind)) {
     names(CNS7)[ind[i]] <- mylist[[i]]
}
```

Comment: I am accepting this as answer since this solves the problem I have in hand. However if this is not too much to ask and since I am still learning, may I request you to also help on that for loop i.e. where was that going wrong.

Comment: @HimanshuM updated the solution